# BufferedWriter line separator becomes double line separator

Tags: java, linux, newline, bufferedwriter

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.csv", true));
bw.append(System.lineSeparator());
bw.append("Text after writing"));
```

The above code will result in below:

```
Text already in file before writing

Text after writing
```

Without System.lineSeparator(), it will become:

```
Text already in file before writingText after writing
```

What I want is:

```
Text already in file before writing
Text after writing
```

I have tried \n and bw.newLine() as well, but all gives the same result. Why is it leaving 2 lines, and how to avoid it?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/fu6Vpr), writing to a `StringWriter`. How are you viewing the file contents? What does `cat test.csv | xxd` show?

Comment: What ist the output of `file test.csv`? I guess you have a problem with the program you use to display the file, not with the file itself. Or maybe you use  ftp in text mode to transfer the file, and it gets broken on the way.

Comment: @AndyTurner That command shows '...' before "Text after writing"

Comment: @ammoQ I'm using gedit to view the file. I never transfer the file anywhere. My program will write to the file, and then read it immediately. It crash when it reads a blank line and try formatting it. I open gedit and indeed there's a blank line somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code and it works as expected.

**Code**:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.csv", true))) {

    bw.append("Text after writing");
    bw.append(System.lineSeparator());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**test.csv** before:

```
1. Text already in file before writing
```

**test.csv** after:

```
1. Text already in file before writing
2. Text after writing
```

Probably the file you are editing already ends with a new line. You may consider checking that before appending.

Note: used a [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for code simplicity.

Note: tested on: jre1.8.0_77, Win7(x64)